# Need background sound + play once

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have a script and when it detects a difference it plays a little alert sound. When it alerts the sound plays but loops, how can I stop this?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to play the sound?

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dbj_sound
AJAX Response = html
code:
   if($("box").html() != html){
     
      $.dbj_sound.play('#soundContainer');


   }

Comment: Can you put that (or the most up-to-date code) in the body of your question? Click the 'edit' link up near your question.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing this? You're not still using the code people used in the early nineties to embed MIDI files into web pages, are you?

```
<embed src="file.wav" autostart="true" loop="false" volume="100" hidden="true" />
```

Comment: I have found the problem. It compares old HTML to the new response. if they are different they sound. For some reason it thinks they're different everytime request comes through even though they're not :/

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("box").html() != html)
```

Getting the `html()` (`innerHTML`) from a node won't return the same markup as was originally parsed to form the contents of the node. The browser can output attributes in any order, with any type of quoting style, change whitespace, change case, choose to `&`-escape differently, etc. You will have to keep the old HTML return value in a variable to compare against.

Comment: var oldHTML = $("#chatbox").html();
 $.ajax({  
  url: "logs/log.html",  
  cache: false,  
  success: function(html){
   
   if(oldHTML != html){
      $("#soundContainer").html('<embed src="alert.mp3" autostart="true" loop="false" volume="100" hidden="true" />');
   }

Comment: You're still getting `oldHTML` from `.html()`! You need to store the previous value of the `html` argument to compare against. Serializing document content with `html()` will not give you the same string you put in.

Comment: Yeh but the oldHTML is before the AJAX request?

Comment: Then you will have to have the original HTML in a JavaScript string variable, or another mechanism to detect changes such as a last-modified-time. You *cannot* get back the original markup of a page from `innerHTML`/`html()`; once it has been parsed it does not exist any more. Page content at run-time is stored as `Element`, `Attribute`, `Text` etc. Node objects, which when serialised back to HTML will almost certainly result in different markup to that from which it was parsed.